# How can I import a multipage PDF as a multipage page layer in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: layers, adobe-acrobat, actions

I've got a 288 page 4-colour PDF and a 288 page text black PDF. is there a way that I can import the text black PDF as a layer across all the 288 4-colour pages? At the moment I can only seem to do this manually one page at a time.

Comment: With some very elementary programming skills, you can write a script using PDFTK that does this.